# Android 10. MediaStore. Getting all images

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

I try to get all images. I use this code:

```
 val galleryImageUrls = mutableListOf<String>()
    val columns = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    val orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN

    appContext.contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
        null, null, "$orderBy DESC"
    )?.use { cursor ->
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            galleryImageUrls.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)))//get Image from column index
        }
    }
```

This code works if I use compileSdkVersion 28, but it doesn't work on compileSdkVersion 29.
Do you have any ideas how I can fix it? Or should I use storage access framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This code works if I use compileSdkVersion 28

It will not be reliable. There is no guarantee that `DATA` will hold a value that you can use.

> Do you have any ideas how I can fix it?

```
    val galleryImageUrls = mutableListOf<Uri>()
    val columns = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    val orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN

    appContext.contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
        null, null, "$orderBy DESC"
    )?.use { cursor ->
        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)

            galleryImageUrls.add(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: DATA is still in the latest documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media). It is still marked as deprecated in `MediaStore.class` of API level 30 though. It seems like someone forgot to remove the @deprecated annotation, as data is available once again

Answer (score 1):

```
{

    ArrayList<Photo> listPhotoPhone = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        // Codigo version de api 29 en adelante

        cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
        );

        if (null == cursor) {
            return listPhotoPhone;
        }

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String photoUrl = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID))).toString();
                Photo photo = new Photo(photoUrl);
                listPhotoPhone.add(photo);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } else {

        cursor = contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " DESC"
        );

        if (null == cursor) {
            return listPhotoPhone;
        }

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String fullPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                Photo photo = new Photo(fullPath);
                listPhotoPhone.add(photo);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
    return listPhotoPhone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Juan Carlos Suarez Marin, but with this code still got nothing.
Nothing shows in logcat

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Build
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import java.util.*




 @SuppressLint("Range")
 fun queryImageStorage2(context:Context) {
  
   val listPhotoPhone: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
   var cursor: Cursor
   val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
  
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
     // Codigo version de api 29 en adelante
     cursor = contentResolver.query(
       MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID),
       null,
       null,
       MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
     )!!
     if (null == cursor) {
//       return listPhotoPhone
       Log.d("ooo","photoUrl")
     }
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
         val photoUrl = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
           MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
           cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID))
         ).toString()
//         val photo = Photo(photoUrl)
         listPhotoPhone.add(photoUrl)
         Log.d("ooo",photoUrl)
       } while (cursor.moveToNext())
     } else {
  
       cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
         MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " DESC"
       )!!;
  
       if (null == cursor) {
         Log.d("ooo","photoUrl")
//         return listPhotoPhone;
       }
  
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
            var fullPath:String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
//           Photo photo = new Photo(fullPath);
//           listPhotoPhone.add(photo);
           Log.d("ooo",fullPath)
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
  
     }
   }
 }
```